# Source of PrimaryControl (CRM Parameter)

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps-modeldriven, crm-ribbon-workbench

In Ribbon Workbench I had created custom button(custom action with help Custom JS Action, so set Crm Parameter like PrimaryControl).

In JS function for example is bottom, we pass formContext and can using API methods.

[Pass Customer Engagement data from a page as a parameter to ribbon actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/customize-dev/pass-dynamics-365-data-page-parameter-ribbon-actions?view=op-9-1) contain info about

> To pass in the execution context (form context or grid context) information to JavaScript function for your ribbon actions, specify PrimaryControl for the form context,

Does "PrimaryControl" contains anything else? What is contains other Crm Parameters?

```js
var APP = APP || {};
APP.GetValue = GetValue || {
    GetCount: (formContext) => {
        formContext.getAttribute("attribute_name");
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Dev Dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [blog](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/alfwynjordan/2019/10/02/getting-dynamics-365-formcontext-from-ribbon-workbench), it will give your more idea about crm parameetrs.

In addition if you add debugger to your function and open browser develeoprs tool, you can debug and look more into your PrimaryControl which will be formcontext or executionContext